# CABasicAnimation Position.Y

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i just want to animate the position of my UIButton with this function:

```
CABasicAnimation *moveUp;
    moveUp          = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
    moveUp.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.retestBTN.frame.origin.y];
    moveUp.toValue  = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.retestBTN.frame.origin.y - 50];
    moveUp.duration = 1.0;
    moveUp.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    moveUp.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
    moveUp.delegate = self;
    [[retestBTN layer] addAnimation:moveUp forKey:@"y"];
```

and then i want to animate it back later that time with that function:

```
CABasicAnimation *moveDown;
moveDown            = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
moveDown.fromValue  = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.retestBTN.frame.origin.y];
moveDown.toValue    = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.retestBTN.frame.origin.y + 50];
moveDown.duration   = 1.0;
moveDown.removedOnCompletion = NO;
moveDown.fillMode   = kCAFillModeForwards;
[[retestBTN layer] addAnimation:moveDown forKey:@"y"];
```

But this does not work properly, my UIButton goes to wierd positions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a CAAnimation you are only animating the Layer. And you don't actually ever change the `modelLayer` of the object, only the `presentationLayer` as you only create the animation and never actually change the `position` property of the layer. This means that the button never actually moves, just where it is drawn on screen moves.

If your button is a UIButton then it will still receive touches where the view is, not where the layer is. You can animate any view much more easily using UIKit like so:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect frame = self.retestBTN.frame;
                     frame.origin.y -= 50;
                     self.retestBTN.frame = frame;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     //callback code goes here
                 }];
```

Comment: If you are only _moving_ the view, why not animate the `center` instead?

Comment: That absolutly works perfect! But is there a callback Method when the animation is finished?!

Comment: Thank you very much...i really love Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 20):

The problem you are facing is that the position is not the same as the origin.

Anyway, you are doing a relative animation of the position so it would be easier if you skip the `toValue` and `fromValue` and instead use the `byValue` property (with the relative change). Your code would look like this:

```
CABasicAnimation *moveUp;
moveUp          = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];      
moveUp.byValue  = @(-50.0f); // or [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-50.0f] if you really need to
moveUp.duration = 1.0;
moveUp.removedOnCompletion = NO;
moveUp.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
moveUp.delegate = self;
[[retestBTN layer] addAnimation:moveUp forKey:@"y"];
```

and

```
CABasicAnimation *moveDown;
moveDown            = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
moveDown.byValue    = @(50.0f); // or [NSNumber numberWithFloat:50.0f] if you really need to
moveDown.duration   = 1.0;
moveDown.removedOnCompletion = NO;
moveDown.fillMode   = kCAFillModeForwards;
[[retestBTN layer] addAnimation:moveDown forKey:@"y"];
```

Comment: I found this answer more useful than the accepted, particularly using `byValue` instead of `fromValue` and `toValue`.

Comment: Answer is pure gold